# How to unsquish DataLoader UI

Tags: lightning, data-loader, ui, user-interface

How to fix the squished UI for dataloader. See Image below.
Machine specs: 4k res display, Windows, x64

[image]

Comment: Looks like the Data Loader isn't handling display scaling well. Maybe give setting your display scaling to 1x would help (other than making everything look really small on your 4K display). If you have a 1080p display around, using that could fix the issue (as I think display scaling generally starts above 1080p).

Comment: Also: Data Loader is on [Github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader), recommend opening an issue with them.